# Game server/Postgresql runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference, postgresql panics and shuts down

Tags: postgresql, game-engine, remote-desktop

I'm hosting a game server from a remote host and to start up the game, it requires launching the postgresql portable, then launching the login server. I am getting this error which completely shuts down the login server, thus, shutting down player's ability to connect to postgresql protable, which is the database. Any help would be dearly appreciated.

None of the other topics have helped me thus far.

```
2022/10/11 19:01:19 User ID: a2e2c5f1-3dcd-483b-ac3e-af4519c6bfa7
2022/10/11 19:01:19 Character ID: 1430   Character Name: Nojiko
2022/10/11 19:01:20 runtime error: slice bounds out of range [:15] with capacity 13
2022/10/11 19:01:20 goroutine 1792231756 [running]:
runtime/debug.Stack()
    C:/Program Files/Go/src/runtime/debug/stack.go:24 +0x65
github.com/ePecetek/aso-legend/factory.init.0.func1.1()
    C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Hero/factory/init.go:192 +0xb9
panic({0xb51fe0, 0xc00c405f08})
    C:/Program Files/Go/src/runtime/panic.go:838 +0x207
github.com/ePecetek/aso-legend/player.(*CastSkillHandler).Handle(0xad4840?, 0xc00b29ce40, {0xc00ae7a000, 0x11028a0?, 0xd})
    C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Hero/player/attack.go:445 +0x1db
github.com/ePecetek/aso-legend/factory.init.0.func1(0xc00b29ce40, {0xc00ae7a000, 0xd, 0xd}, 0x4203)
    C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Hero/factory/init.go:211 +0x20e
github.com/ePecetek/aso-legend/database.(*Socket).recognizePacket(0xc00b29ce40, {0xc00ae7a000?, 0xc0104ebd00?, 0x1?})
    C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Hero/database/socket.go:186 +0x69c
github.com/ePecetek/aso-legend/database.(*Socket).Read.func1()
    C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Hero/database/socket.go:103 +0x49
created by github.com/ePecetek/aso-legend/database.(*Socket).Read
    C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Hero/database/socket.go:102 +0x2d
2022/10/11 19:01:20 User ID: a2e2c5f1-3dcd-483b-ac3e-af4519c6bfa7
2022/10/11 19:01:20 Character ID: 1430   Character Name: Nojiko
2022/10/11 19:01:21 runtime error: slice bounds out of range [:15] with capacity 13
2022/10/11 19:01:21 goroutine 1792353999 [running]:
runtime/debug.Stack()
    C:/Program Files/Go/src/runtime/debug/stack.go:24 +0x65
github.com/ePecetek/aso-legend/factory.init.0.func1.1()
    C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Hero/factory/init.go:192 +0xb9
panic({0xb51fe0, 0xc005249bf0})
    C:/Program Files/Go/src/runtime/panic.go:838 +0x207
github.com/ePecetek/aso-legend/player.(*CastSkillHandler).Handle(0xad4840?, 0xc00b29ce40, {0xc00cdc7000, 0xc00cfe0800?, 0xd})
    C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Hero/player/attack.go:445 +0x1db
github.com/ePecetek/aso-legend/factory.init.0.func1(0xc00b29ce40, {0xc00cdc7000, 0xd, 0xd}, 0x4203)
    C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Hero/factory/init.go:211 +0x20e
github.com/ePecetek/aso-legend/database.(*Socket).recognizePacket(0xc00b29ce40, {0xc00cdc7000?, 0xc0152eeea0?, 0x1?})
    C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Hero/database/socket.go:186 +0x69c
github.com/ePecetek/aso-legend/database.(*Socket).Read.func1()
    C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Hero/database/socket.go:103 +0x49
created by github.com/ePecetek/aso-legend/database.(*Socket).Read
    C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Hero/database/socket.go:102 +0x2d
2022/10/11 19:01:21 User ID: a2e2c5f1-3dcd-483b-ac3e-af4519c6bfa7
2022/10/11 19:01:21 Character ID: 1430   Character Name: Nojiko
2022/10/11 19:08:26 runtime error: slice bounds out of range [:15] with capacity 14
2022/10/11 19:08:26 goroutine 1844002136 [running]:
runtime/debug.Stack()
    C:/Program Files/Go/src/runtime/debug/stack.go:24 +0x65
github.com/ePecetek/aso-legend/factory.init.0.func1.1()
    C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Hero/factory/init.go:192 +0xb9
panic({0xb51fe0, 0xc00c404330})
    C:/Program Files/Go/src/runtime/panic.go:838 +0x207
github.com/ePecetek/aso-legend/player.(*CastSkillHandler).Handle(0xad4840?, 0xc00d02a720, {0xc00e6cb000, 0xc000682000?, 0xe})
    C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Hero/player/attack.go:445 +0x1db
github.com/ePecetek/aso-legend/factory.init.0.func1(0xc00d02a720, {0xc00e6cb000, 0xe, 0xe}, 0x4203)
    C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Hero/factory/init.go:211 +0x20e
github.com/ePecetek/aso-legend/database.(*Socket).recognizePacket(0xc00d02a720, {0xc00e6cb000?, 0xc00ba9b3f0?, 0x1?})
    C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Hero/database/socket.go:186 +0x69c
github.com/ePecetek/aso-legend/database.(*Socket).Read.func1()
    C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Hero/database/socket.go:103 +0x49
created by github.com/ePecetek/aso-legend/database.(*Socket).Read
    C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Hero/database/socket.go:102 +0x2d
2022/10/11 19:08:26 User ID: 2ffecb7d-ce5d-460e-808f-4b2ae7741ff2
2022/10/11 19:08:26 Character ID: 1088   Character Name: Leonardo
2022/10/11 19:12:04 runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
2022/10/11 19:12:04 goroutine 124562962 [running]:
runtime/debug.Stack()
    C:/Program Files/Go/src/runtime/debug/stack.go:24 +0x65
github.com/ePecetek/aso-legend/auth.exploreWorld.func1()
    C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Hero/auth/start_game.go:322 +0x51
panic({0xadc4e0, 0x10e79d0})
    C:/Program Files/Go/src/runtime/panic.go:838 +0x207
github.com/ePecetek/aso-legend/database.(*Character).SpawnCharacter(0xc01291cc00)
    C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Hero/database/characters.go:922 +0x1f8b
github.com/ePecetek/aso-legend/auth.explorePlayers(0xc00e553ec0)
    C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Hero/auth/start_game.go:357 +0x2a8
github.com/ePecetek/aso-legend/auth.exploreWorld(0x3b9aca00?)
    C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Hero/auth/start_game.go:326 +0x45
github.com/ePecetek/aso-legend/auth.(*StartGameHandler).startGame.func1()
    C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Hero/auth/start_game.go:107 +0x47
created by github.com/ePecetek/aso-legend/auth.(*StartGameHandler).startGame.func2
    C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Hero/auth/start_game.go:264 +0x32
2022/10/11 19:13:36 runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
2022/10/11 19:13:36 goroutine 124562962 [running]:
runtime/debug.Stack()
    C:/Program Files/Go/src/runtime/debug/stack.go:24 +0x65
github.com/ePecetek/aso-legend/auth.exploreWorld.func1()
    C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Hero/auth/start_game.go:322 +0x51
panic({0xadc4e0, 0x10e79d0})
    C:/Program Files/Go/src/runtime/panic.go:838 +0x207
```

And the main.go:

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "math/rand"
    "net"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "sort"
    "strconv"
    "time"

    "github.com/ePecetek/aso-legend/ai"
    "github.com/ePecetek/aso-legend/api"
    "github.com/ePecetek/aso-legend/config"
    "github.com/ePecetek/aso-legend/database"
    _ "github.com/ePecetek/aso-legend/factory"
    "github.com/ePecetek/aso-legend/logging"
    "github.com/ePecetek/aso-legend/nats"
    "github.com/ePecetek/aso-legend/redis"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "github.com/robfig/cron"
    "github.com/thoas/go-funk"
)

var (
    logger = logging.Logger
    path   = "payments.txt"
    // CacheFile to store state to be transferred
    CacheFile = "cache.json"
)

func initDatabase() {
    for {
        err := database.InitDB()
        if err == nil {
            log.Printf("Connected to database...")
            return
        }
        log.Printf("Database connection error: %+v, waiting 30 sec...", err)
        time.Sleep(time.Duration(2) * time.Second)
    }
}

func initRedis() {
    for {
        err := redis.InitRedis()
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("Redis connection error: %+v, waiting 30 sec...", err)
            time.Sleep(time.Duration(2) * time.Second)
            continue
        }

        if redisHost := os.Getenv("REDIS_HOST"); redisHost != "" {
            log.Printf("Connected to redis...")
            go logger.StartLogging()
        }

        return
    }
}
func StartLogging() {
    fi, err := os.OpenFile("Log.txt", os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND, 0666) //log file
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error opening file: %v", err)
    }
    log.SetOutput(fi)
}

func startServer() {
    cfg := config.Default
    port := cfg.Server.Port
    listen, err := net.Listen("tcp4", ":"+strconv.Itoa(port))
    defer listen.Close()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Socket listen port %d failed,%s", port, err)
        //os.Exit(1)
    }
    log.Printf("Begin listen port: %d", port)
    StartLogging()
    //initQuest()
    //connections = make(map[string]net.Conn)
    //remoteAddrs = make(map[string]int)

    for {
        conn, err := listen.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalln(err)
            continue
        }
        ws := database.Socket{Conn: conn}
        //ws.SetPingDuration(time.Second * 5)
        //ws.SetPingHandler(nil)
        go ws.Read()
    }
}

func writeCache(ids []string) error {
    data, _ := json.Marshal(ids)
    return ioutil.WriteFile(CacheFile, data, 0644)
}

func addCointToPlayers(id string, amount uint64) {
    f, err := os.OpenFile("payments.txt", os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY, 0644)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    defer f.Close()
    paymentslogger := log.New(f, "", log.LstdFlags)
    user, err := database.FindUserByID(id)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    } else if user == nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    user.NCash += uint64(amount)
    user.Update()
    paymentslogger.Printf("%d nCash loaded to %s (%s).", amount, user.Username, user.ID)
}

type Payment struct {
    ID     string `db:"id" json:"id"`
    userID string `db:"user_id" json:"user_id"`
    amount string `db:"itemid" json:"itemid"`
}

func paymentsHandler() {
    logdb, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:stNveTJx6cCMRu4x@tcp(localhost:3306)/payment?charset=utf8")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    } else {
        c := cron.New()
        c.AddFunc("@every 1m", func() {
            results, err := logdb.Query("Select id,user_id, itemid FROM payments WHERE player_receive = '0'")
            if err != nil {
                panic(err.Error())
            }
            for results.Next() {
                var pay Payment
                err = results.Scan(&pay.ID, &pay.userID, &pay.amount)
                if err != nil {
                    panic(err.Error())
                }
                amount, err := strconv.ParseUint(pay.amount, 10, 64)
                addCointToPlayers(pay.userID, amount)
                update, err := logdb.Query("UPDATE payments SET player_receive = '1' WHERE id = '" + pay.ID + "'")
                if err != nil {
                    panic(err.Error())
                }

                defer update.Close()
            }
        })
        c.Start()
    }

}

func cronHandler() {
    c := cron.New()
    c.AddFunc("0 0 0 * * *", func() {
        database.RefreshAIDs()
    })
    c.Start()
    database.RefreshAIDs()
}
func test() {
    /*database.FiveClans[1].ClanID = 14
    err := database.FiveClans[1].Update()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Err: ", err)
    }*/
}
func main() {
    cmnd := exec.Command("postgresql/PostgreSQLPortable.exe", "arg")
    //cmnd.Run() // and wait
    cmnd.Start()
    initRedis()
    initDatabase()
    //paymentsHandler()
    test()
    cronHandler()
    ai.Init()
    database.RefreshOnline()
    go database.UnbanUsers()
    s := nats.RunServer(nil)
    defer s.Shutdown()
    c, err := nats.ConnectSelf(nil)
    defer c.Close()

    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    go api.InitGRPC()
    startServer()
}

func resolveOverlappingItems() { //67-306
    ids := []string{}

    for _, userid := range ids {
        fmt.Println("user id:", userid)
        bankSlots, _ := database.FindBankSlotsByUserID(userid)
        freeSlots := make(map[int16]struct{})
        for _, s := range bankSlots {
            freeSlots[s.SlotID] = struct{}{}
        }

        findSlot := func() int16 {
            for i := int16(67); i <= 306; i++ {
                if _, ok := freeSlots[i]; !ok {
                    return i
                }
            }
            return -1
        }

        for i := 0; i < len(bankSlots)-1; i++ {
            for j := i; true; j++ {
                if len(bankSlots) == j+1 || bankSlots[i].SlotID != bankSlots[j+1].SlotID {
                    break
                }

                free := findSlot()
                if free == -1 {
                    continue
                }

                fmt.Printf("%d => %d\n", bankSlots[j+1].SlotID, free)
                freeSlots[free] = struct{}{}
                bankSlots[j+1].SlotID = free
                bankSlots[j+1].Update()
            }
        }
    }
}

type IntRange struct {
    min, max int
}

// get next random value within the interval including min and max
func (ir *IntRange) NextRandom(r *rand.Rand) int {
    return r.Intn(ir.max-ir.min+1) + ir.min
}

func createServerMobs(server int) {
    aiSet := funk.Filter(funk.Values(database.AIs), func(ai *database.AI) bool {
        return ai.Server == 1
    }).([]*database.AI)

    sort.Slice(aiSet, func(i, j int) bool {
        return aiSet[i].ID < aiSet[j].ID
    })

    for _, ai := range aiSet {
        newAI := *ai
        newAI.ID = 0
        newAI.Server = server
        err := newAI.Create()
        if err != nil {
            log.Print(err)
        }
    }
}

func protect(f func()) {
    defer func() {
        if err := recover(); err != nil {
            log.Printf("Recovered: %v", err)
        }
    }()

    f()
}
```

Comment: This is nothing to do with your PostgreSQL installation. Your Go code is throwing an error because it is trying to access a range in a slice that extends beyond the backing array. See if there is a support forum for wherever you got the code from.

Comment: Beyond @RichardHuxton suggestion, there is something odd in `paymentsHandler`. Is it trying to connect to MySQL? And is that correct?

Comment: There is no support forum, unfortunately.